# Go from nullable to non-nullable after ReadFromJsonAsync

Tags: c#, nullable, .net-6.0

`ReadFromJsonAsync` method returns nullable T. Here is a code sample:

```
private async Task<T> Get<T>(Uri url, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    using HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url, cancellationToken);

    T? body = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<T>(cancellationToken: cancellationToken);

    return body ?? throw new Exception();
}
```

I want my method to return non-nullable value.

I am wondering when `ReadFromJsonAsync` will return null. No matter how I have tried I was still getting instance of T with all properties equal null. So I hoped that it would be safe to write code like this:

```
    return (T)body;
```

But now I am getting a warning **Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.**

What about this, is it a good idea:

```
    return body!;
```

Comment: @Ergis Is it safe to say that value returned by ReadFromJsonAsync is never null?

Comment: Why you need it non-nullable so badly? If you can't change the contract, then return a default value.

Comment: @Ergis body.Value does not work: 'T' does not contain a definition for 'Value' etc

Comment: @Ergis That's wrong, `T` is not a `Nullable<T>`. There is no `.Value`.

Comment: I don't think it can actually ever return null and I'm not sure why it was written to return a nullable reference instead of just throwing.  If you go with `return body!;` then if somehow it is null then eventually you'll just get a NRE the first time you try to deference it.  The `return body ?? throw new Exception()` will on the other hand throw immediately which personally I think is better practice.  Though I'd use something like `InvalidOperationException` with a message about the failure.

Comment: @juharr what do you think about "return body!;" in this situation?

Comment: @walruz I updated my comment.  My rule of thumb is to use the null forgiveness operator as little as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ReadFromJsonAsync` is a utility method that gets the response's content stream and then passes that to `JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync`.

`DeserializeAsync` is defined as returning a nullable value, because it *might* return null. It will do so in the case where you attempt to deserialize a `null` JSON value.

If you don't expect those, then you can use `!` to just ignore the warning. But the safest way would be to indeed check for null and either throw an exception or return a fallback balue.